# Microsoft Azure to embedded device communcation

Tags: azure, embedded, rtos, iot

I have a question about an Azure IoT project based on Windows Azure. In short; it's an embedded application (ARM based device, running on a custom RTOS) who's sending device information to Windows Azure using the recently announced Serverbus Event Hub. It's using the HTTS endpoint of the Event Hub to send it's information to. So for so good.

But now I want to "talk" to the device from the cloud. Basically, I have a website running on Azure, and I want to send commands to that device (which is not 100% of the time connected, as it's an on-the-field device). What's the best way to do this? What technologies can I use?

Do I need to use Sockets, TCP connections, long-polling HTTP requests, ..? The big 'thing' is that the device is running a custom RTOS, so there are no libraries or whatsoever available..

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can think about AMQPS and Azure Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions. Create a subscription with a filter (e.g. by device name or ID) for each device and send annotated messages to the topic.

Count of subscriptions limited by 2000 for 1 topic.